# Run maven install only if files changed in scm

Tags: maven, svn, jenkins

I have a Jenkins build which basically does the following:
1) svn update
2) mvn clean install
3) run some custom deploy script

How do configure this job to skip step 2) if there are no changed files in SVN?
I don't need to rebuild the WAR if nothing changed.

I thought that this is what the "incremental build" checkbox is for, but that didn't work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Addd Polling on SVN. WHich will trigger build only if there is a change

Answer (score 0):

In your build configuration, under "Build Triggers" add a Poll Scm. If you want Jenkins to check for changes every minute type `* * * * *` in the schedule box. Otherwise, use the blue question mark next to the schedule box to help you with cron syntax.